# Update parent view from child view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Xcode 5 (iOS SDK 7.0). I am trying to update an element inside the parent View from a child view.

I have the following files:
ViewOneController
ViewTwoController

Inside the ViewOneController, I am adding ViewTwoController as a subview with the following code:

```
[self.view addSubview:ViewTwoController];
```

I have a UIImageView declated in ViewOneController.h

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *box;
```

I would like to update the backgound color of the box from ViewTwoController. I know that I can update the background color with the following code.

```
[box setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

But this works only in the ViewOneController. I have a function called updateColor is ViewTwoController. I want to update the color of the Box from that function.

Comment: You could use delegate methods.

Comment: I forgot to say, I am totally new to iOS app development, so an example more a reference to an example is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your naming convention is a little confusing. UIView subclasses typically don't include Controller as part of the name. Probably the best approach would be as per Justafinger's solution. Except, given that viewTwoController is a UIView subclass the @interface declaration in your viewTwoController would read; "@interface ViewTwoController : UIView" (minus the quotation marks - SO complains about notification when "@" is used)

Answer (score 0):

One quick and not so clean way to do it would be to call your parentviewcontroller directly :

```
[((ViewOneController*)self.parentViewController).box setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

However like Larme suggested it, i believe the cleanest way would be to use delegate, it is used to notify a change after the user did something. Here is a tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

You would have to create a delegate protocol in your ViewTwoController.h

```
@protocol ViewTwoDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)somethingHappenedInViewTwoController;
@end

@interface ViewTwoController : UIViewController 
....
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<ViewTwoDelegate> delegate;
```

In your ViewOneController you would have to set your controller as the delegate to viewTwoController.
In ViewOneController.h you first declare that your controller implement ViewTwoDelegate protocol

```
@interface ViewOneController:UIViewController<ViewTwoDelegate>
```

and in ViewOneController.m when you create your viewtwoController :

```
viewtwoController = [[ViewTwoController alloc] init];
viewtwoController.delegate = self;
```

and you add the following method below

```
- (void)somethingHappenedInViewTwoController{
    [box setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Then in your ViewTwoController.m you would call this method, it will call the method implemented in ViewOneController

```
[self.delegate somethingHappenedInViewTwoController];
```

Comment: I haven't tried the delegate one yet. The first one doesn't work. Gives me the following error: "Property 'parentViewController' not found on object of type 'ViewTwoController *'"

Comment: If ViewTwoController is a UIView (that's a really bad name by the way), you have to use delegates